# eclipse / aptana - text compare show code syntax highliging

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I am using Aptana 3 which is basically a modified version of eclipse, so i think this question is applicable to both

Before I commit code in I like to review my changes via the text compare.  It allows me to double check things I have changed.

However although text has been highlighted for changes made it does not keep the php syntax highlights.  Is there anyway I can keep the PHP or whatever syntax highlighting when viewing differences?

See screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I have tried the text compare on the normal eclipsePDT and it keeps the syntax highlighting.

I think the solution for it is the file associations built into the file compare, however still have no clue how to link them up.  Normal editing of php xml css files etc it highlights the code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that a plugin author must implement, and, it seems that it's still not implemented for Aptana's PHP editor, so, the proper thing to have that would be reporting this as a bug to be fixed in a future Aptana Studio 3 version.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - ive reported the issue and its now going to be fixed in the next version 3.1 of aptana

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the Eclipse editor. Perhaps you can try opening the file in another editor. Right click on the file and go to open with and choose different PHP Editor.

I am not a PHP programmer but perhaps you can check these links to see if you can find and alternate plugin with the features you want.

- http://eclipse.org/proposals/php-ide/
- http://www.phpeclipse.com/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but im looking for syntax highlighting within the eclipse text compare, regardless if the source is php, java etc.  Im looking for it to use eclipse own built in highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) is *not* "a modified version of Eclipse". Aptana is *based on* the Eclipse *Platform*. I am using the [Aptana Studio 3 plugin for Eclipse](http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download) (3.7.1; because of [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) and features like "Local Filesystem"). ISTM that this is a problem with the Aptana PHP Editor, which the [Eclipse PDT editor](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) takes preference over in Eclipse (that might be due to the fact that I had installed the PDT plugin first).

You can try to work around this if you install PDT in Aptana Studio 3 (if necessary and possible), and define the PDT editor as default for PHP files (in Eclipse, and perhaps Aptana as well, it is under Window → Preferences → General → Editors → File Associations). You can also report this as an Aptana bug. Or use Eclipse with the Aptana Studio 3 plugin in the first place; IMHO, most Aptana editors, including the Aptana PHP editor, are not much of an improvement over the "built-in" Eclipse editors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been repotorted on aptana bug tracker (by me) and apparently it is going to be fixed with 3.1

the bug tracking number is APSTUD-3922 for anyone who is interested